# Order the data with multiple conditions in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, date, datetime, jupyter-notebook

I have a data like this:

```
ID   daea01               date02                  ID_NUM
AAA  2000-01-01 00:00:00  2000-02-02 01:01:01     12345
BBB  2000-05-01 00:00:00  2000-03-02 01:01:01     52489
AAA  2000-05-01 00:00:00  2000-01-02 01:01:01     12548
AAA  2000-01-01 00:00:00  2000-02-01 01:01:01     78954
...
AAA  2000-01-01 00:00:00  2000-08-02 01:01:01     12345
BBB  2000-05-01 00:00:00  2000-06-02 01:01:01     52489
AAA  2000-05-01 00:00:00  2000-06-02 01:01:01     12548
BBB  2000-01-01 00:00:00  2000-02-02 01:01:01     78954
...
```

I want to sort the data:

1. Sort by AAA & BBB
2. For each AAA or BBB, order date01 from the oldest datetime
3. For the combination of AAA and date01, sort date02 (the same datetime group together and order from the oldest datetime as well)

This is the expected result:

```
ID   daea01               date02                  ID_NUM
AAA  2000-01-01 00:00:00  2000-02-01 01:01:01     78954
AAA  2000-01-01 00:00:00  2000-02-02 01:01:01     12345
AAA  2000-01-01 00:00:00  2000-08-02 01:01:01     12345
AAA  2000-05-01 00:00:00  2000-01-02 01:01:01     12548
AAA  2000-05-01 00:00:00  2000-06-02 01:01:01     12548
BBB  2000-01-01 00:00:00  2000-02-02 01:01:01     78954
BBB  2000-05-01 00:00:00  2000-03-02 01:01:01     52489
BBB  2000-05-01 00:00:00  2000-06-02 01:01:01     52489
...
```

Very new to Python, thank you in advance.

Comment: What is the issue, exactly? Which part are you struggling with? Have you tried anything, done any research? Stack Overflow is not a free code writing service, nor is it an alternative to tutorials and documentation. See: [tour], [ask], [help/on-topic], https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can sort your Dataframe like this:

```
df.sort_values(by=['ID', 'daea01','date02'])
```

Comment: assign it back or add inplace=True

Comment: ensure the date times are actual date times too for a bonified solution ;)